# Python 2d matrix class bug

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started to create a 2d matrix class that stores either int or float inside a data structure. I would like this data structure to support indexing. For example, matrix[1][2] is first row and second col. To do, I attempted to add **getitem** to the class. However, the error message I receive is **getitem** takes two arguments. The code is below and the failing unit test case is below.

```
"""
Matrix Data Structure 
"""

class Matrix:
    def __getitem__(self, row, col):
        return 1 
        
def test_get_item():
    matrix = Matrix() 
    assert matrix[0][0] == 1 

def main():
    test_get_item() 
    print('hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are trying will not work.. the `__getitem__` will only accept only one argument.

To achieve what you want you may need something like this:

```
In [1]: class MatrixRow:
   ...:     """Its just a list.."""
   ...:     def __init__(self, length):
   ...:         self.__items = [0] * length
   ...:     def __getitem__(self, index):
   ...:         return self.__items[index]
   ...:
   ...:
   ...: class Matrix:
   ...:     def __init__(self, rows, cols):
   ...:         self.__rows = [MatrixRow(cols)] * rows
   ...:     def __getitem__(self, index):
   ...:         return self.__rows[index]
   ...:

In [2]:

In [2]: m =  Matrix(2,3)

In [3]: m[0]
Out[3]: <__main__.MatrixRow at 0x2b81aa09148>

In [4]: m[0][0]
Out[4]: 0
```